# zWeather unit parameter does not seem to work

Tags: jquery

Has any one use zWeather widget to display unit in Fahrenheit? I try to set the unit option to 'f' or 'F' and it doesn't seem to change the unit display. I downloaded the latest example v1.3.1 http://www.zazar.net/developers/jquery/zweatherfeed/, opened example_jquerytools.html, added the "unit: 'f' " option and it still displayed unit in Celsius. What am I missing?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#test').weatherfeed(['UKXX0085','EGXX0011','UKXX0061','CAXX0518','CHXX0049'],{},function(e) {
       $("div.scrollable").scrollable({ 
            unit: 'f',
            vertical: true,  
            size: 1,
            circular: true
       }).navigator().autoscroll({
              interval: 3000
          });
    });
});
</script>
```

html

```
<div class="scrollable vertical">
    <div id="test" class="items"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yay. I found the sucker. The unit: 'f', in the question above, is not supposed to be there. It's supposed to be in the bracket after the location parameter. Duh!!!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#test').weatherfeed(['UKXX0085','EGXX0011','UKXX0061','CAXX0518','CHXX0049'],{unit:'f'},function(e) {
        $("div.scrollable").scrollable({ 
            vertical: true,  
            size: 1,
            circular: true
        }).navigator().autoscroll({
              interval: 3000
           });
    });
});
</script>
```